# Extension of Markov Model with Time Dependence and Emissions

Tags: time-series, markov-process, hidden-markov-model, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am interested in a continuous time system with $n$ observable factors $s_1(t),\ldots,s_n(t)$ and a discrete process $z(\tau_i)\in\{0,1\}$ with random emission times $\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_m$. The observable factors are believed to have a relationship with the emission value and/or likelihood of emission at a given time. Ideally the model can be calibrated to provide distributions for $\tau_{i+1}$ and $z(\tau_{i+1})$ for some time $t\ge \tau_{i}$.

Such a model seems somewhat related to a tradition Hidden Markov Model in that there is a state space, $s_i(t)$ in this case, but in this particular instance, the states are fully observable in continuous time. Moreover, a Continuous-Time Markov Model does not handle the concept of "emissions" but rather transitions between states.

Is there a particular name for this type of system? Is there some transformation that can be made to transform this system into a classical Markov model framework?